# How to compare a selected value from mysql database with an existing one in another table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I got the following code where i select a random value from my sql table but i want to stop it from selecting a duplicate.

```
// Call on a random style ID to display in rating window.
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT pictureID,userID FROM styles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc() ){
    $rateableUserID = $rows['userID'];
    $rateablePictureID = $rows['pictureID'];
}
```

The goal is something like tinder in this case. You get a random picture (in tinder a random person) and vote but the already voted picture by then should not reapear in this selection from my table. My goal was to compare the selected value with the value in a users table where every one of those id's is being marked as already voted by him.
Has anyone an idea of how to achive something like that?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table for user perviews, that stores numbers that have been retrieved before for this user

Users Table

```
+------+--------+--------+
|USERID|USERDATA|USERDATA|
+------+--------+--------+
|1     |  XXXX  |  XXXX  |
+------+--------+--------+
|2     |  AAAA  |  AAAA  |
+------+--------+--------+
|3     |  ZZZZ  |  ZZZZ  |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Userviews table

```
+------+---------+
|USERID|pictureID|
+------+---------+
|1     |     1   |
+------+---------+
|1     |     2   |
+------+---------+
|2     |     3   |
+------+---------+
|3     |     3   |
+------+---------+
|3     |     2   |
+------+---------+
```

Picture Table

```
+----------+----+
|PICTUIREID|DATA|
+----------+----+
|1         |WWWW| 
+----------+----+
|2         |EEEE|  
+----------+----+
|3         |RRRR|  
+----------+----+
```

And then your query will be

```
SELECT p.pictureID FROM Userviews uv
join picture p on p.PICTUIREID = uv.PICTUIREID 
where uv.USERID <> (userID )
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: What i had in mind is to create a column where every pictureID is being written down and compared if it is already written down.

Comment: To be honest, I don't totally understand what are you trying to achieve, my answer above is for the Tinder case. You will have a record for each picture that a user have viewed.